# I had just started learning programming in C language and I faced a simple problem, How can use the if condition to run this code?

Tags: c

I want to write a program that accepts three arguments from the command line. Two arguments are
numbers while one argument is one of the operations. The main function
should read these arguments, if the number of arguments is not 3, then the program should
return the value -9999 and exit.

If the number of arguments is 3, then the program should perform
the operation between the two numbers and return the result of the operation.

I have written several lines but I know my code is not complete yet.
Could anyone help me to write the correct one? I want to check the number of arguments first then apply the operation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
void main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int a, b, result;
    char ch;
 
    printf("enter two numbers and the operation to apply on: \n");
    a = atoi(argv[1]);
    b = atoi(argv[2]);
    ch  = *argv[3];
    printf("%d %d %c", a, b, ch);
    switch (ch)
    {
    case '+':
        result = a + b;
        break;
    case '-':
        result = a - b;
        break;
    case 'x':
        result = a * b;
        break;
    case '/':
        result = a / b;
        break;
}
    printf("\nThe result of the operation is %d", result);
    printf("\n");    
}
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific, why is the code not complete?

Comment: To start with - change `main()` function return type to `int` and include `stdlib.h` (required for `atoi()`). You also need to do some error handling around arguments count and argument values.

Comment: " if the number of arguments is not 3" This means you need to check `argc` to see how many arguments that were passed. Note that it is at least 1 since the name of the executable is always passed in `argv[0]`.

Comment: @bereal the code is not complete bc it first have to check the number of arguments then if they are 3 apply the operation. someone has just helped me with this. Than you

Comment: That's important information that you didn't include in the question.

Comment: @Lundin yeeees yess got it thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> if the number of arguments is not 3

Check `argc` before you try to access the arguments.

```
if (argc != 4) {
    /* Print usage message and exit */
}
```

---

> if the number of arguments is not 3, then the program should return
> the value -9999 and exit.

That's an arbitrary requirement. Use `EXIT_FAILURE` and `EXIT_SUCCESS` instead cluttering the code with magic numbers.

---

```
atoi(argv[1]);
```

provides no means of error checking. Consider using `strtol()` instead.

Aside:

- Division by zero would exhibit undefined behaviour.
  From C11 6.5.5 paragraph 5:

> The result of the / operator is the quotient from the division of the
> first operand by the second; the result of the % operator is the
> remainder. In both operations, **if the value of the second operand is
> zero, the behavior is undefined.**

- You are missing a header file.
- `main()` should be declared to return an `int`.
- Those operations could result in an integer overflow/underflow.